# How to relaunch a thread in Qt?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qthread

I'm using a separate thread for serial port communication. This thread should launch when we want to connect with serial port and finish when there was an error/disconnection.

The issue is that if the thread has finished once, it doesn't relaunch the next time we want to reconnect.

```
SerialIO::SerialIO(SettingsDialog *settings) :  //Worker. Extends QObject
    settings(settings)
{
    serial = new QSerialPort(this);
}

SerialIO::~SerialIO()
{
    serial->close();  
    //something else?  
}


/* PUBLIC SLOT */
void SerialIO::connectSP()
{ 
    /* connects with some port, if not succesfull, emits an error signal */ 
}
```

---

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
    //...
    serialio = new SerialIO(settings);
    serialio->moveToThread(&thread);  

    QObject::connect(&thread,SIGNAL(started()),serialio,SLOT(connectSP()));
    QObject::connect(&thread,SIGNAL(finished()),serialio,SLOT(deleteLater()));  
    QObject::connect(serialio,SIGNAL(error(const QString)),this,SLOT(handleError(const QString&)));      
    //...

}

void MainWindow::connect()   
{
    if(!thread.isRunning()){              
        thread.start();
    }

}

void MainWindow::handleError(const QString &msg){
    QMessageBox::information(this, "Error", msg);
    if(thread.isRunning()){
        thread.quit();
        thread.wait();
    }
}
```

It seems that the thread doesn't finish properly, but I've already checked the thread is not running! Then the program finish unexpectedly.

---

Solution:

```
QObject::connect(&thread,SIGNAL(started()),serialio,SLOT(connectSP()));
QObject::connect(&thread,SIGNAL(finished()),serialio,SLOT(disconnectSP()));
QObject::connect(serialio,SIGNAL(bye()),&thread,SLOT(quit()));
```

Comment: The thread *does* finish properly, but your expectation that the `SerialIO` object will magically get destroyed is wrong. You must destroy the `SerialIO` object yourself *once the thread has been waited on*. There's no need for the `isRunning` check. Simply do: `thread.quit(); thread.wait(); delete serialIO;`.

Comment: Your first mistake is in `serialio = new SerialIO(settings);`. You can't move object to another thread if is has any `QObject` parent. Porbably, you should try QtConcurrent (QRunnable) for such case.

Comment: @DmitrySazonov That's not a parent. The code is in error though, because this pattern implies that the `SerialIO` class is using an object (the dialog) directly from another thread, and that most likely is an error. We'd need to see the code that's used from that other thread. The suggestion to use `QRunnable` is rather generic I'd say. **None of the code shown is a problem in itself**. It's the code that's *not shown* that *is the problem*.

Comment: @firescreamer The [documentation states otherwise](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qthread.html#finished).

Comment: @thuga check the source code. Events are posted to event lists of thread in witch objects lives. If thread has finished there is no event loop to post it.

Comment: @firescreamer I tested the code and it does get deleted.

Comment: @firescreamer You can see in the [source code](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtbase/source/000ee3d503906c2c20f789b6b9dd95b8647405d0:src/corelib/thread/qthread_win.cpp#L367), that delete events are processed after the `QThread::finished` signal has been emitted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`deleteLater()` posts an event to the event queue (like a repaint event, a timer event or a network event). If the event is processed it deletes the object. If there is no event loop your object isn’t deleted.

You are quitting the thread first which cause your object not to be deteted and consequently your destructor does not get called.

You should connect `finished()` signal of the thread to a slot to disconnect :

```
QObject::connect(&thread,SIGNAL(finished()),serialio,SLOT(disconnectSP())); 

void SerialIO::disconnectSP()
{ 
    serial->close();
}
```

Also there is no need to call `deleteLater()` as you are newing your object once.